# Excel for Win 2010 and Mac 2011 passwords

Tags: windows, mac, microsoft-excel-2010, passwords

I got a `.xlsm` file created on Windows (**Excel 2010**) that can be opened on Mac (**Excel 2011**).

However, when opening the Editor to view the VBA modules the password (known on Windows) is said to be "incorrect" on the Mac (the password has been regenerated on Windows to prevent mistakes).

Two questions

- Is there some known VBA Password-protection incompatibility between Win Excel 2010 and Mac Excel 2011?
- If yes, is there a way to fix the Mac version?

---

Note: I tried the password-reset method (DPB... e.g. [this link](http://lbeliarl.blogspot.com)) but that doesn't work well on Mac

Comment: What part(s) of the XLSM file are actually protected?  What's the EXACT error message you get when you try the password?

Comment: In *Developer ► Editor ► VBAProject*. Clicking on it asks for a Password. Incorrect password message is "Project Locked. Invalid password".